# Safe width in pixels for printing web pages?

Tags: css, printing

What is the safe width in pixels to print a web page?

My page includes large images and I want to make sure they will not be cut of when printed.

I know about different browser margins and US Letter / DIN A4 paper sizes. So we got standard letter sized and some default DPI values. But can I convert these into **pixel** values to specify in the image's `width` attribute?

Comment: instead using width in pixels, you should use `width:auto` which will adjust content width to the width of the paper

Answer (score 92):

As for a true “universal answer”, I can’t provide one.  I can, however, provide a simple and definitive answer for some particulars...

> > 670 PIXELS

At least this seems to be a safe answer for Microsoft products.  I read many suggestions, including 675, but after testing this myself 670 is what I came up with up.

All the DPI, margin issues, hardware differences aside, this answer is based on the fact that if I use print preview in IE9 (with standard margins) – and SET THE PRINT SIZE TO 100% rather than the default of “shrink to fit”, everything fits on the page without getting cut off at this width.

If I send an HTML email to myself and receive it with Windows Live Mail 2011 (what Outlook Express became) and I print the page at 670 width – again everything fits.  This holds true if I send it to an actual hard copy or a an MS XPS file (virtual printout).

Before I experimented, I was using a arbitrary width of 700.  In all the scenarios mentioned above part of the page was getting cut off.  When I reduced to 670, everything fit perfectly.

As for how I set the width – I just used a primitive “wrapper” html table and defined it’s width to be 670.

If you can dictate the end user’s software, such matters can be straight forward.  If you cannot (as is usually the case of course) you can test for particulars like which browsers they are using, etc.  and hardcode the solutions for the important ones.  Between IE and FF, you will cover literally about 90% of web users.  Put in some other code for “everyone else” which generally seems to work and call it a day...

Comment: I would just like to add a comment that while at the time of this answer FF and IE may have held between them 90% share of the browsers used (i find it unlikely with google offering chrome to just about any person who searched with any other browser which imo is at the moment a better lighter browser) but its unlikely that they still do as trends change and a browser share often changes like any other market share.

Comment: This answers the question, although it is obviously more complicated than a simple px size.

Answer (score 47):

It's not as straightforward as looks. I just run into a similar question, and here is what I got: First, a little background on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch).

Next, in CSS, for paper, they have `pt`, which is point, or 1/72 inch. So if you want to have the same size of image as on the monitor, first you have to know the DPI/PPI of your monitor (usually 96, as mentioned on the wikipedia article), then convert it to inches, then convert it to points (divide by 72).

But then again, the browsers have all sorts of problems with printable content, for example, if you try to use float css tags, the Gecko-based browsers will cut your images mid page, even if you use   page-break-inside: avoid; on your images (see here, in the [Mozilla bug tracking system](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104040)).

There is (much) more about printing from a browser in this article on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).

Furthermore, you have to deal width "Shrink to Fit" in the print preview, and the various paper sizes and orientations.

So either you just figure out a good image size in inches, I mean points, (7.1" * 72 = 511.2 so `width: 511pt;` would work for the letter sized paper) regardless of the pixel sizes, or go width percentage widths, and base your image widths on the paper size.

Good luck...

Comment: I actually had an easier time just creating a PHP Image GD version of the material I wanted to print (postcards, flyers, etc.) which I just fed info from a db and it reformatted itself accordingly.  I just kept the ratio of pixels correct.  4x6 postcard (350dpi) == 2135x1435 px

Answer (score 21):

One solution to the problem that I found was to just set the width in inches. So far I've only tested/confirmed this working in Chrome. It worked well for what I was using it for (to print out an 8.5 x 11 sheet)

```
@media print {
    .printEl { 
        width: 8.5in;
        height: 11in;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not taking the page margins into account. Or the possibility of A4 paper sizes.

Comment: This was perfect for me, it makes so much sense.

Comment: @Blazemonger with `@media print`, you can set those. You can set `size: letter` or `size: A4`. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/

Comment: @J.Ko That wasn't the point; it's the end user who might use either A4 or letter paper, and the CSS designer can't be certain which one is available to the user.

Answer (score 10):

For printing I don't set any width and remove any obstacles which keep your print layout from having a dynamic width. Meaning if you make your browser window smaller and smaller, no content is cut/hidden but the document just gets longer. Like this, you can be sure that the rest will be handled by the printer/pdf-creator.

> What about elements with a fixed width such as images or tables?

#### Images

Options I can think of:

- scale images down in your print CSS to a width which you can assume will fit in any case, use pt not px (but print will need more points/unit anyways, so this should hardly be a problem)
- exclude from being printed

#### Tables

- remove the fixed width
- use landscape if you really have tables with loads of information
- don't use tables for layout purposes
- exclude from being printed
- extract content, print it as paragraphs

http://www.intensivstation.ch/en/css/print/

or any other google result for combinations of: CSS, print, media, layout

Comment: But what about elements with a fixed width such as images and tables?

Comment: The link on the answer gives a 404

Answer (score 5):

A printer doesn't understand pixels, it understand dots (pt in CSS). The best solution is to write an extra CSS for printing, with all of its measures in dots.

Then, in your HTML code, in head section, put:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="style_print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">
```

Comment: But images needs width and height attributes specified in pixels. I need to convert PT values to pixel based on the printer standard DPI and dimension.

Comment: Then you have to play with the image containers... or apply trial and error ;) However, I think using two separated CSS files, one for screen and another for print, is a good practice.

Comment: give the `<img>` tag a surroundig `<div>` the div gets width an height in pt and the img gets `width:100%; height:100%;`

Answer (score 5):

A solution to ensure that images don't get cut when printed in a Web page is to have the following CSS rule:

```
@media print { 
  img { 
    max-width:100% !important;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is one... It depends on browser, on printer (physical max dpi) and its driver, on paper size as you point out (and I might want to print on B5 paper too...), on settings (landscape or portrait?), plus you often can change the scale (percentage), etc.
Let the users tweak their settings...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using chrome/puppeteer to print the PDF and I got the exact height and width for letter size as 1056px and 816px

I'm using below CSS

```
@media print { @page { size: letter; margin: 0in 0in; width: 816px; height: 1056px; } }
```