# printing page with text cut off on right side

Tags: html, css, printing-web-page

when i give the page to print...
the text on the right hand side of the page gets cut off....
i gave text align left in print css but still not working...
providing my code below....

http://jsfiddle.net/jjnKP/

```
@media print {
  body {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    line-height: 1.4em; 
    word-spacing:1px; 
    letter-spacing:0.2px;
    font: 17px Arial, Helvetica,"Lucida Grande", serif; 
    color: #000;
  }

  .mainDiv, .navbar,
  .copyright  {
    display: none;
  }

  #templateTwoPadding {
    padding: 0 0;
  }

  #tableHeadingLastDF {
    text-align: left;
    width: 134px; 
    border:1px solid white;
  }

  #makeLeftDF {
    text-align: left;
  }

  .jumbotron .lead {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: you probably have a fixed width set for the body somewhere in the screen css. Try setting the body width to 100% in the print css.

Comment: Or `#tableHeadingLastDF{width: 134px;}` is simply not wide enough?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jjnKP/ included my fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same thing happen to me on a project...everything kept getting cut off on the right side. :(

I ended up "fixing" it by simply setting a width and being happy with it. I don't think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11084797/743533) is the exact one I got my information from but looks good just the same.

Answer (score -4):

I had same problem with SVG graphs, below css is worked for me.

```
@media print {
    body {transform: scale(.6);}
}
```

Comment: This fix did not work for me.  Everything is smaller, as you would expect, but it's still cut off on the right side.

Comment: this still cuts off the right. just minimises the content.