# How do you change the width of a div when printing?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

The div is currently set at col-lg-8. I want it to be col-lg-12 only when I print. I am already removing the component that was taking the rest of the space when I am printing.

I realized that @media print does not work. I am wondering it I should be using something related to d-print.

Comment: you should use this attribute for you print css: media="print"

Comment: What do you mean by print css?

Comment: This is an XY question. I believe it should be "Why is @media print not working?"

Comment: Try using `@media print` again but add `!important` to all the styles inside.

Comment: Well @media print won't work because I wanted to change it from col-lg-8 to col-lg-12. I don't believe this is possible because col-lg is a predefined class from bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Bootstrap for your project (by using class `.col-lg-8`). Unfortunately, **Bootstrap doesn't come with a defined grid for printing media query, they just have some responsive utility classes to make certain content visible/hidden on print**, you have to defined it your own.

The required steps are quite straightforward to update, assuming you have this in your HTML:

```
<div class="container project-name">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-print-12">AA</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-print-6">BB</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need a CSS block section defined specific to be used in printing.

```
@media print {
  .project-name .col-print-1{ width: calc(1/12 * 100%); }
  .project-name .col-print-2{ width: calc(2/12 * 100%); }
  ...
}
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199429/bootstrap-grid-for-printing) for more information about Bootstrap grid for printing

Comment: Where do I place the @media print block?

Comment: in your CSS file, like `style.css`, usually this is placed at the end of CSS, it just works like responsive media queries

Comment: you can test this using Chrome, try to open Print dialog and set your paper size, or even save as a PDF file to check, no need to print in real