# Rails 6/Bootstrap 4 classes don't work in print media

Tags: bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I am managing Bootstrap 4 via Webpacker in my app, and have namespaced Bootstrap 4 because most of the app is still in v3.

I have a file `app/javascripts/stylesheets/bs4-namespace.scss` that looks like this:

```
.bs4 {
  @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss";
}
.bs4-full {
  @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
}
```

Then in my `layouts/application.html.erb` I have:

```
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

And the relevant line in `application.js` is

```
import 'stylesheets/bs4-namespace'
```

This does work for the screen media and v4 classes render correctly. However, when I print it, the Bootstrap selectors are no longer effective.

What might be causing Bootstrap to be disabled in print media?

Comment: Could you provide a working jsfiddle? Curious on the outputted .bs4 classes. Also the BS4 grid for print media is only available for xs screens: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199429/bootstrap-grid-for-printing

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

The main issue being that the media type is not declared. Since it is not the media defaults to 'screen' only. Therefore any CSS that is imported from Webpacker would only be applied to screens and not media link which can including print. More info on the media tag [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp).