# What is the width of a webpage that I need to set for printing?

Tags: printing, width

I want to make a page in my website that users can print.

I searched in Google about CSS print stylesheet, I don't want this!

I want to make a separate page for printing, what is the max width that the page should be for A4 pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safe Width in Pixel for Printing Web Pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320357/safe-width-in-pixel-for-printing-web-pages)

Comment: Try this post which has some great discussion[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320357/safe-width-in-pixel-for-printing-web-pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320357/safe-width-in-pixel-for-printing-web-pages)